# Calculate GrandTotal in VueJS2

Tags: html, vue.js

I want to Calculate row of Total in `Vuejs2` like pic Below
[image]

By following Code

```
     <tr v-for="(product, index) in form.items" :key="index">
        <td class="saleTable--td">{{ product.name }}</td>
        <td class="saleTable--td">{{ product.code }}</td>
        <td class="saleTable--td">
            <input type="number" class="saleTable--input" v-model="form.items[index].quantity">
        </td>
        <td class="saleTable--td">
            <input type="number" 
                class="saleTable--input" 
                placeholder="0.00" 
                v-model="form.items[index].unit_price"
            >
        </td>
        <td class="saleTable--td">
            <input 
                type="number" 
                class="saleTable--input" 
                placeholder="0.00" 
                v-model="form.items[index].discount"
            >
        </td>
        <td class="saleTable--td">
            USD {{ discountedPrice(product)  | formatMoney }}
        </td>
        <td class="saleTable--td">
            <v-btn @click="removeProduct(index)" small icon color="red">
                <v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="(item, key) in form.items" :key="key">
        <th class="saleTable--total" colspan="5">Total</th>
        <td>USD {{ GrandTotal(item) }} </td>
    </tr>
```

**IN my Script, i used `reduce` to calculate**

```
methods: {
            GrandTotal(product) {
                let s = (product.unit_price - (product.unit_price * product.discount / 100)) * product.quantity;
                return  this.form.items.reduce((total, item) => {
                    return total + (item.s);
                }, 0);
            },
   }
```

I tried above but its not working, its Gots `NaN` Like in Pic..

Any Help, Please???

Comment: You need to show us what your data looks like. Are `product.unit_price`, `product.pdiscount`, `product.quantity` all numbers?

Comment: Does `item.s` really exists? You're creating the `s` variable, just outside of the reduce, which is never used. Aren't you supposed to make this `s` calculation inside the reduce, using the `item.*` properties instead of the `product.*`?

Comment: @Jesper still no help..

Comment: @Terry yeah, its all number..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using, any values from `this.form.items` array.
Change your return statement to,
simply get the value of variable `s` inside the reduce method

```
return  this.form.items.reduce((total, item) => {
      let s = (item.unit_price - (item.unit_price * item.discount / 100)) * item.quantity;
      return total + s;
}, 0);
```